# How to custom webView.showFindDialog dialog layout?

Tags: android, webview, dialog

I have `WebView`, in this webview i want find text, I was iclude code `webView.showFindDialog`, when I was open it, I don't like it.
I want change everything: backgroud color, text color, destination of it dialog, utc.
How I can custom it dialog layout?